# Increment loop iteration one by one with click issue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to increment through an array of objects, but one by one. Its working as is but one condition is not working I am incrementing based on `questions.length` but that does not seem to work and I get the error `app.js:70 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>` which makes sense because the code is trying to increment to an element that does not exist as the `questions.length` is not working.

If i add `if ((i + 1) == (questions.length)){i--;}` it stops it incrementing but it stops it 1 before the last item.

Code so far:

```
const questions = [
  {
    question: 'This is question one?',
    answerOne: 'Answer One 1',
    answerTwo: 'Answer Two 1',
  },
  {
    question: 'This is question Two?',
    answerOne: 'Answer One 2',
    answerTwo: 'Answer Two 2',
  },
  {
    question: 'This is question Three?',
    answerOne: 'Answer One 3 ',
    answerTwo: 'Answer Two 3',
  },
  {
    question: 'This is question Four?',
    answerOne: 'Answer One 4 ',
    answerTwo: 'Answer Two 4',
  },
];

const genHtml = () => {
  let innerDiv = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    console.log(questions[i].question, i);
    let item = questions[i];
    innerDiv += `${questions[0].question}`;
    if (answersDiv) {
      answersDiv.style.display = 'block';
      yesBtn.innerHTML = `${questions[0].answerOne}`;
      noBtn.innerHTML = `${questions[0].answerTwo}`;
    }
    if (yesBtn) {
      yesBtn.addEventListener ('click', () => {
        if (i < questions.length) {
          i++;
          console.log(questions[i].question, i);
          answer1Count++;
          console.log('answer 1 count =' + answer1Count);
          const mainDiv = document.getElementById (
            'main'
          ).innerHTML = `${questions[i].question}
          `;
          yesBtn.innerHTML = `${questions[i].answerOne}`;
          noBtn.innerHTML = `${questions[i].answerTwo}`;
        } 
          if ((i + 1) == (questions.length)){
                i--;
            }
      });
    }
    if (noBtn) {
      noBtn.addEventListener ('click', () => {
        if (i < questions.length) {
          i++;
          answer2Count++;
          console.log('answer 2 count =' + answer2Count);
          const mainDiv = document.getElementById (
            'main'
          ).innerHTML = `${questions[i].question}
          `;
          yesBtn.innerHTML = `${questions[i].answerOne}`;
          noBtn.innerHTML = `${questions[i].answerTwo}`;
          }
          if ((i + 1) == (questions.length)){
            i--;
        }
      });
    }
  }
  return innerDiv;
};
```

Comment: Perhaps `(questions.length)` return true but not a number, remove the parenthesis to see

Comment: Have you tried to state - let questions - instead of -const questions-?

Comment: Thanks but that gives the same outcome

Comment: I think its more to do with the `if (i < questions.length)` condition, as if the array has no next object/item then it should not increment, but this does and the `if ((i + 1) == (questions.length)){ i--;}` stops it incrementing but it does it one item before the last

Comment: That should not make a difference as I am not editing the original array, its just data for the UI

Comment: Shouldn't it make a difference or definitely doesn't? Right now I can't test .. but you can try maybe ..
I hope it works .. Hello

Comment: Thanks Just tried it but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... now see the .lenght

```
 const questions = [
    {
      question: 'This is question one?',
      answerOne: 'Answer One 1',
      answerTwo: 'Answer Two 1',
    },
    {
      question: 'This is question Two?',
      answerOne: 'Answer One 2',
      answerTwo: 'Answer Two 2',
    },
    {
      question: 'This is question Three?',
      answerOne: 'Answer One 3 ',
      answerTwo: 'Answer Two 3',
    },
    {
      question: 'This is question Four?',
      answerOne: 'Answer One 4 ',
      answerTwo: 'Answer Two 4',
    },
  ];
  
  const genHtml = () => {
    let innerDiv = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      console.log(questions[i].question, i);
      let item = questions[i];
      innerDiv += `${questions[0].question}`;
      if (answersDiv) {
        answersDiv.style.display = 'block';
        yesBtn.innerHTML = `${questions[0].answerOne}`;
        noBtn.innerHTML = `${questions[0].answerTwo}`;
      }
      if (yesBtn) {
        yesBtn.addEventListener ('click', () => {
          if (i < questions.length) {
            i++;
            console.log(questions[i].question, i);
            answer1Count++;
            console.log('answer 1 count =' + answer1Count);
            const mainDiv = document.getElementById (
              'main'
            ).innerHTML = `${questions[i].question}`;
            yesBtn.innerHTML = `${questions[i].answerOne}`;
            noBtn.innerHTML = `${questions[i].answerTwo}`;
          } 
            if ((i + 1) == (questions.length)){
                  i--;
              }
        });
      }
      if (noBtn) {
        noBtn.addEventListener ('click', () => {
          if (i < questions.length) {
            i++;
            answer2Count++;
            console.log('answer 2 count =' + answer2Count);
            const mainDiv = document.getElementById (
              'main'
            ).innerHTML = `${questions[i].question}`;
            yesBtn.innerHTML = `${questions[i].answerOne}`;
            noBtn.innerHTML = `${questions[i].answerTwo}`;
            }
            if ((i + 1) == (questions.length)){
              i--;
          }
        });
      }
    }
    return innerDiv;
  };
```